# Using hidden input in POST Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I need to send a POST to an express controller, using previous data from a get.

I have an email being sent out for a reset password link. User clicks the link, which looks like `example.com/user/reset/[reset token]`

User enters new password, and then posts the request updating the db.

But I can't seem to post the reset token with the request

This in my GET controller

```
res.render('resetPassword');
req.body['hiddenToken'] = req.params.token;
```

But in my POST controller, I can't seem to access that `req.body.hiddenToken` key

My handlebars code for the hidden input
`<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="hiddenToken">`

GET controller

```
// User Reset GET Route -> verifies token, adds a hidden elm to page, posts data
router.get('/reset/:token', (req, res) => {
    PasswordToken.findOne({token: req.params.token})
        .then(token => {
            if (!token) {
                res.render('resetPassword');
                req.body['hiddenToken'] = req.params.token;

            }
            else {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'Token not Found, Try Submitting Again');
                res.redirect('/user/login')
            }
        })
});
```

And in POST, `console.log(req.body);` returns

```
{ hiddenToken: '',
  password: '123456789',
  passwordConf: '123456789' 
}
```

Maybe there is a way in handlebars to inject the params into the `value` tag?

Comment: Could you show the complete GET request code?

Comment: @JonasWilms Just did! Thanks

Comment: As a sidenote, you show *Token not found*, if *the token is actually there*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting properties on `req.body` doesn't make much sense in a route, 
as it will be lost afterwards (the request *ends*). As you said, you could pass the token to handlebars:

```
     res.render('resetPassword', { token: req.params.token });
```

Then inside handlebars, add it as the input value:

```
 <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="hiddenToken" value="{{token}}">
```

Now the token gets sent to the client inside the HTML, then when the user sends the form the token will get sent back as part of the POST requests data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I appreciate it. I am new to express so I don't know things.